# Powershell | using sAMAccountName get userdetails

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

I am trying this,

```
dsquery * -filter "samaccountname=biswajit" -attr homemdb
```

In powershell, by using `samaccountname` of the user, i should be able to get users `homemdb`, `Display Name`, `Description`, `Department`, `Job Title, Manager`, `Mobile`, `Home`.

Comment: Haven't dealt with dsquery in ages but... There are plenty of examples on the TechNet site where that dsquery-line was originally posted. What you need to do is to add the desired attributes after `-attr`. Like `-attr homemdb samaccountname` etc. Use `dsquery * -filter "samaccountname=<The Actual SamAccountName>" -attr *` to get all attributes.

Comment: @notjustme that worked, but he did not fetch managers name

Comment: what's the relation to powershell?

Comment: Under Organization, i have a managers name that also needs to be part of my output

Comment: @Avshalom PowerShell is a shell after all so I'd say it's related as long as dsquery is being run under PowerShell. I'm not quite sure I'd call this development however.

Comment: @notjustme anyway to get the managers name also ?

Comment: @GovG Yes, I would assume including the manager attribute would return this value to the screen. Make sure the user actually has a manager set on the user object in ADUC.

Comment: Yeah, it gave me the info needed